# iOS - Really weird behavior on Shadow below button not being rendered every time

Tags: ios, swift, shadow, bezier

```
import UIKit

class ShadowView: UIView {

   override var bounds: CGRect {
       didSet {
          setupShadow()
       }
    }

    private func setupShadow() {
       self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
       self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.5)
       self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
       self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
       self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)).cgPath
       self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
       self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

I have this class that act like a shadow for some buttons.  Sometimes though, the shadow does not render. It happened only once (so 0.001% of the times) in my device (iPhone 6s Plus) and is happening on simulator of iPhone X on an element Z while on iPhone 5s element Z is fine and element Y is buggy (while on iPhone X element Y is fine).

So, there seems to be no pattern at all. The only pattern is that the elements that are not rendered in a device keeps not being rendered no matter how many times I restart the app, etc

Why isn’t the shadow rendering every single time? What is happening?

Comment: Could it be because bounds are being set only in init in those cases? `didSet` will not be called upon setting properties from `init`.

Comment: @Lukas, I actually just set the class to a UIView on a xib (storyboard). The `UIView` custom-classed to `ShadowView` is constrained to have exactly the same boundaries as the button that is above it (so that it can act as its shadow). What do you think I should do?

Comment: Try calling `setupShadow()` from `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Did you end up getting this one solved? I'm running into the same situation.